# Invalid Char in key name in Constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way that i enclosed a key name like OCN_# in my constructor class as it complains about invalid char ? My external Data Source has a key field that is called OCN_# and my class looks like this

```
class sample_class {
    constructor( OCN_#,OCN_NAME,ABBRE_OCN_NAME) {
    this.OCN_# = OCN_#
    this.OCN_NAME = OCN_NAME
    this.ABBRE_OCN_NAME = ABBRE_OCN_NAME }}
```

i tried enclosing it with square brackets or ` with no luck ? i want to avoid having to change the key name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by quoting the key name and using square brackets to access it. **However, I would strongly recommend against doing this as it is a poor style choice IMO.**

```js
class sample_class {
    constructor( OCN_NUM, OCN_NAME, ABBRE_OCN_NAME) {
        this["OCN_#"] = OCN_NUM
        this.OCN_NAME = OCN_NAME
        this.ABBRE_OCN_NAME = ABBRE_OCN_NAME
    }
}
```

**Note:** you cannot use the `#` character in a variable name: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

> You use variables as symbolic names for values in your application. The names of variables, called identifiers, conform to certain rules.
>
> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($). Subsequent characters can also be digits (0–9).
>
> Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) as well as "a" through "z" (lowercase).
>
> You can use most of ISO 8859-1 or Unicode letters such as å and ü in identifiers. (For more details, see this blog post.) You can also use the Unicode escape sequences as characters in identifiers.
>
> Some examples of legal names are Number_hits, temp99, $credit, and _name.